# how to convert a MapDataset to tensor

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

i'm using tensorflow_io_bigquery_client in order to read data from bq.
each record has 4 integer elements.

but i need to transform it into tensor (4 integer each).

so i have something like:

```
tensorflow_io_bigquery_client = BigQueryClient()
read_session = tensorflow_io_bigquery_client.read_session(..)

dataset = read_session.parallel_read_rows()
dataset = dataset.map (transofrom_row)
#todo convert it into tensor (but i guess it should be an iterator or something like this because the dataset is hugh?

k_means_estimator = tf.compat.v1.estimator.experimental.KMeans(num_clusters = num_clusters, use_mini_batch = False, relative_tolerance = 1)

fit = k_means_estimator.train(input_fn=lambda: to_tensor(dataset), steps=1000) 
# todo convert dataset into tensor
```

Comment: I wanted to ask the exact same question, any way out? Mentors.....

Comment: Does [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/io/tutorials/bigquery#load_census_data_in_tensorflow_dataset_using_bigquery_reader) help you to address your problem. Thanks!